# initializing array of arrays populated with same element

Tags: c#, arrays

```
var board = Enumerable.Repeat(Enumerable.Repeat('.', 3).ToArray(), 3).ToArray();
board[0][0] = 'Q';
```

Here I'm trying to create array of arrays (3*3) populated with same element.
But when I try to change one element ([0,0]) it changes first element of all three arrays. Why is that and how can this behavior be fixed without having 2 loops to initiate arrays?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not declaring board as an array from the get-go?  Perhaps if you do you can declare which array you want to reach.

Comment: @EthanTheBrave It doesn't matter if OP declared it as `char[][] board` or not, `var` handles it the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Enumerable.Repeat()` returns the thing you give it. It doesn't create a new copy of it each time.

The inner `Enumerable.Repeat()` returns the character '.' three times. Chars are a "value type", meaning that this creates a new copy of the character 'y':

```
char x = 'y';
```

You can't *not* create a copy of a value type when you assign it.

But arrays are a reference type, and the rules are different. The outer `Enumerable.Repeat()` returns *the same array object* three times. You're not passing in an instruction to create a new array three times. You're passing in a reference to an existing array, and saying "give me that thing, three times". And unlike a character, giving you the same array again doesn't create a copy of it.

Arrays are a "reference type", meaning that the second line below creates a new *reference* to the same *object*:

```
char[] a = new [] { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
var y = a;
```

`a` and `y` are *the same object*. If you set `a[0] = 'd';`, you can use the reference `y` to look at that same array object, and you'll see the same letter 'd' in `[0]`.

`Enumerable.Repeat()` returns the same thing x number of times. It's not what you want if you're trying to create multiple instances of a value type.

**This is what you want, if you want Linq:**

```
var board = Enumerable.Range(0, 3)
            .Select(n => Enumerable.Repeat('.', 3).ToArray())
            .ToArray();
```

`Select()` *executes* code each time, so the code you execute can create a new array each time. `Repeat()` just keeps returning whatever value you gave it.

Answer (score 2):

Because you created one array `Enumerable.Repeat('.', 3).ToArray()` and cloned reference to this array 3 times.
So, you have 3 reference onto one value.
You need to initialize every row:

```
var board = Enumerable.Repeat((char[])null, 3).ToArray();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    board[i] = Enumerable.Repeat('.', 3).ToArray();
}
board[0][0] = 'Q';
```